# which one is better to test a valid url in python

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, urllib2, httplib

I want to check whether a particular url exists or not.

I came across two methods.

url = "http://www.google.com"

1.

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
response.code  # check what is the response code
```

2.

```
import httplib 
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url) 
conn.request('HEAD', '/') 
response = conn.getresponse() 
if response.status == 200: # check the status code
    # do something
```

Though both will solve my purpose, but which one is a better method to achieve this purpose.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you formulated your question correctly, then neither method is perfect.

The big problem is that you said "url", but you only check for the scheme "http". URLs however can have different schemes:

> ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/standards/RFC/rfc959.txt
>
> file:///home/somesh/.bashrc
>
> http://www.google.com

"httplib" is not useful for these checks, since it can only handle the "http" scheme. "urllib2" on the other hand can handle all of the schemes I mentioned but the `response.code` is not what you have to check. Instead, you should catch exceptions which will be raised when the resource is not available: `HTTPError` or `URLError` in these cases.

Comment: Thanks.
Actually I have to check only for those urls which will be either a link of google drive file or dropbox file.Thats why I mentioned only http://....     .

Answer (score 2):

You can try something along those lines, the point being, that you usually also want to handle the errors you get, if there is a problem with fetching the url.

```
In [4]: import urllib2

In [5]: def test(url):
   ...:     try:
   ...:         response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
   ...:     except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
   ...:         return e.code,None
   ...:     return response.code,response

In [6]: test('http://www.google.com')
Out[6]: 
(200,
 <addinfourl at 154469068 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x92caa2c>>)

In [7]: test('http://www.google.com/foobar')
Out[7]: (404, None)
```

In reality you would also need to handle `urllib2.URLError`:

```
In [10]: def test(url):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    ...:     except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
    ...:         return err.code, None
    ...:     except urllib2.URLError as err:
    ...:         return err.reason, None
    ...:     return response.code,response

In [11]: test('http://www.google.foo')
Out[11]: (socket.gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'), None)
```